# Getting property of Model c#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, model

Today I have the problem, that I can not access the value of my Model:

```
public class SpecificADModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string AdressBusiness { get; set; }
    public string DirectNumberBusiness { get; set; }
    public string ReceptionNumberBusiness { get; set; }
}
```

I only want the username of this model.

```
public void SearchWholeUser(string fullName){

        UserADSearch searchUser = new UserADSearch();
        List<SpecificADModel> source = new List<SpecificADModel>();
        source = searchUser.SearchFull(path, fullName);

        //string username = the value of username comes here

        //used to initialize the detailed info frame
        initializeInfos(source);
        GetChildRequests(username);
    }
```

Setting the value works fine (happens in another class). May it is possible to get the value out of the list?
I already tried it with:

```
string username = source[1].ToString();
```

But it did not work either.

Any ideas how to get the username without making a new AD request?

Thanks in advance

## Edit

SearchFull() lokks like this (but I think this is not necessary):

```
public List<SpecificADModel> SearchFull(string direction, string fullName)
    {
        //New List in the SpecificADModel format.
        List<SpecificADModel> users = new List<SpecificADModel>();

        try
        {
            // New AD search for clicked user on the lefthandside ListView
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(direction, "admin", "pass", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            //searches for all relevant Infos in AD
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(&(cn=" + fullName + ")))";
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("streetAddress");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homephone");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

            string displayName = result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
            string accountName = result.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();
            string firstName = result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString();
            string lastName = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
            string companyName = result.Properties["company"][0].ToString();
            string departmentName = result.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
            string jobTitle = result.Properties["title"][0].ToString();
            string streetAddress = result.Properties["streetAddress"][0].ToString();
            string homePhone = result.Properties["homephone"][0].ToString();
            string directPhone = result.Properties["telephoneNumber"][0].ToString();

            //Results will be stored in SpeceficADModel Format in the users ListView
            users.Add(new SpecificADModel()
            {
                DisplayName = displayName,
                Username = accountName,
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                CompanyName = companyName,
                Department = departmentName,
                JobTitle = jobTitle,
                AdressBusiness = streetAddress,
                ReceptionNumberBusiness = homePhone,
                DirectNumberBusiness = directPhone
            });

            //returns List<>
            return users;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the question but I think that depends on what SearchFull does inside.

Comment: maybe `string username = source[1].Username;`?

Comment: Did you rebuild the project after you finish adding the properties? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get properties values from your `List<SpecificADModel>`, try this:

```
List<SpecificADModel> source = new List<SpecificADModel>();
string username = source[0].DisplayName;
string username = source[0].Username;
string username = source[0].FirstName;
string username = source[0].LastName;
. . . .
```

Comment: This has worked. Thank you.
Aaaaah I think do understand!
So if it returns multiple usernames, the second username would be 
        source[1].Username;

is this right?

Comment: @ManuelBürge And please mark it as answer to close the topic.

Comment: @ManuelBürge Correct, also you can get those values in `for` loop for example.